# Clickable area moves away from its content after CSS rotation

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a Chrome specific issue with [this collapsible tile](https://jsfiddle.net/Granjow/12jLcquh/).

[image]

The expand button is a `div` with an `onClick` event handler and `cursor: pointer` in CSS. When collapsed, it is rotated by 90 degrees.

- In Firefox (100) and Safari, the button behaves as expected, i.e. the button is clickable and expands the tile again.
- In Chrome (105), the button is not clickable, but the area below it, as in the screenshot above.

Why is this? Does not make sense to me when the div is where it should be but its `cursor: pointer` and `onClick` area are somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue personally by using css `transform` instead of `rotate`

in example, here is a before and after

```css
.expand-button {
    /* other css... */
    /* old css
    transition: rotate 0.5s;
    */
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    &.collapsed {
        /* old css
        rotate: -90deg;
        */
        tranform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
}
```

I can't quite tell you why this fixes it in chrome, but it does  hopefully that helps.

Comment: Fixes the issue indeed! :D Funny. Thanks a lot!